# Cannot start Weblogic Managed Server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Unable to start Weblogic Managed Server. On starting up, the following exception is being seen in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
<Jul 10, 2014 9:45:20 PM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <Waiting for the process to die: null>
<Jul 10, 2014 9:45:20 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed during startup so will not be restarted>
```

Any pointers to what could be causing this would be appreciated.

Env: Weblogic 10.3.5

Comment: A few things to check. Make sure your `nodemanager.properties` file has to correct entries, especially `StartScriptEnabled` and `StartScriptName`. Then check the start script that is referenced for errors. Sounds like you have a syntax error/bad classpath in `startWebLogic.sh` or `setDomainEnv.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to JAVA_HOME pointing to the JDK location under /"Program Files"/...
It causes a lookup on "Files" class which obviously fails.

The solution is to point to a JDK location with no white space in the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding:

```
set CLASSPATH=
```

to the start of the [home]\user_projects\domains[my_domain]\bin\setDomainEnv.sh file.